# UIAlertView Button Accessibility

Tags: ios, accessibility, uialertview, uiaccessibility, kif

```
[UIAlertView alertViewWithTitle:@"" message:@"Submit successfully!" cancelBlock:^(NSInteger buttonIndex) {
} dismissBlock:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonsTitles:nil, nil];
```

This is the `UIAlertView` declaration. However, I desire to UI test `cancelButton`.

```
[tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"cancelButton"];
```

How should I add accessibility to that cancelButton?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think alert views are already accessible.

Comment: What do you mean by `UITest`?

Comment: The author seems to be looking for help dismissing an `UIAlertView` using [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF).

Comment: @Neeku he's using a BDD testing framework which crowbars itself into iOS by hijacking the accessibility properties of UI. The only way you can "press" a button when running UI automated tests.

Comment: Hmmm @Fogmeister, thanks! I was a bit confused even after googling, since I thought it might be an actual UI element!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to dismiss the alert by triggering a tap of the cancel button. You can identify the cancel button by its label, which is "OK" in your case.

Comment: This seems a bit 'unsafe' ... I mean, what about localizable button texts? The answer is correct and i upvoted it but do you see my edge case?

Comment: Just had the answer from my colleague and it's pretty much obvious - for localized apps u may use the localized key for the option.